# Streamlit Can't use Pandas Describe function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, streamlit

So im trying to use describe() function to my dataframe to find some descriptive statistics of the data in my Streamlit webpage. Here is the head of the dataframe:
[image: This is head of my df]

```
st.write(superstore_data.describe(include='all'))
```

But it returns with an exception like this:

```
StreamlitAPIException: ("Could not convert 'CA-2018-100111' with type str: ,tried to convert to int64", 'Conversion failed for column Order ID with type object')
```

I tried describe function directly (not using Streamlit), and it works:

```
import pandas as pd
superstore_data = pd.read_csv('data/superstore.csv')
superstore_data.describe(include='all')
```

the outputs:
[image]

##### So the question is

is there any details i missed from streamlit? Why Streamlit API can't use pandas describe function?

Comment: Please do not post code, data and error messages as screenshots. Have a look here to learn how to improve your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your exception comes from the Streamlit API and not from Pandas itself. You get the error for oder `ID`and not `Ship Mode`. Have you tried to use Pandas `describe()` directly and only on column `Ship Mode`? What is the result?

Comment: @petezurich Ship mode column is not from my dataframe, its just an example from an article i found that a describe function can be use to dtype object. Im sorry btw im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Than again I suggest you provide a concise question with enough details so that others can help you.

Comment: @petezurich yeah i tried directly describe function and it works, so the problem comes from streamlit, thank you

Comment: Then please close the question so that others can see that your matter is solved.

Comment: i think im gonna edit the question and focus on streamlit problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is column Order ID has mixed type when we get the description of a dataframe. So we will convert this column to a string.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Order ID": ["CA-2017-152156", "CA-2017-138688"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.write('Current Dataframe')
st.write(df)

dfd = df.describe(include='all')

# Column Order ID has mixed type, there is int and str.
# Let's convert everything to str for streamlit display.
dfd['Order ID'] = dfd['Order ID'].astype(str)

st.write('Dataframe Description')
st.write(dfd)
```

#### Output

[image]